# Is there a way to get the audio/video file size for a particular format using youtube-dl

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-dl

```
<?php
    $youtubeUrl =  $_GET['url'];
    $content = shell_exec("youtube-dl -j $youtubeUrl "); 
    $meta=json_decode($content);  
    $file= $meta->{'_filename'};
    $fileWithoutExtension = explode(".",$file)[0];
    $extension = ".m4a";
    $file = $fileWithoutExtension . $extension;   

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"" );
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
// $fize = shell_exec("youtube-dl -f 141 --get-size $URL");
// header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);
    passthru("youtube-dl -f 140 -o - $youtubeUrl");

?>
```

See the **commented lines**. I need **those Two** lines. rest of the code is working fine. This file downloads the **audio** from YouTube. But I am not able to see any **file size** while downloading

Comment: no, because you're streaming the download. you'd have to download to a temp file first, then do `filesize()` on that, or do a separate `HEAD` request to the url and hope that youtube outputs the appropriate content-length header itself.

Comment: `--get-size` is not an option of youtube-dl

Comment: @MarcB , no, because the application itself also shows the total filesize during download (and progress.)

Comment: @MarcB I did separate HEAD request to the url but now it starts streaming istead of downloading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because youtube-dl doesn't have an option to display the size, you might want to look into `ytdl` instead, it can give you all the meta-data, like filesizes.

to install:

```
$ pip install pafy
...
$ ytdl [url]
Stream Type    Format Quality         Size            
------ ----    ------ -------         ----            
1      normal  webm   [640x360]       21 MB           
2      normal  mp4    [640x360]       24 MB           
3      normal  flv    [320x240]       19 MB           
4      normal  3gp    [320x240]       15 MB           
5      normal  3gp    [176x144]        5 MB 
...
```

(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pafy )

Comment: Is there a way to get the exact filesize in octect ?

Comment: Doesn't work on Win10. `AttributeError: 'YtdlPafy' object has no attribute 'encode'`.